# What statistical method that I can use to compare mean of cases that selected from different studies?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mean

I have a data that contains demographic information and primary variables (A,B,X,Y,Z) that extracted from past 20 years literature review. All those literature reviews are about case study, so in the data that we collected, each row is a person that selected from different case studies. Therefore, the data is like the regular data that contain every information for each person, like age, sex, A, B, X, Y, Z. But each person is not collected like regular sample collection, is from case studies from literature review.

I want to compare mean difference between A and B, also the mean difference among X, Y, Z. But I guess that we can't use T-test or ANOVA for this kind of situation right? Does anyone know what statistical methods should I conduct in this situation? And how to do it? Thank you! Hopefully that I express myself clearly.